# Find Closest Neighbors - OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I do have a set of openCV Point2f type image points (coordinates). I want to find the 4 nearest neighbors of each point in that set. Is there any specific build-in function in openCV to do this or should I measure the distance between each point and decide the four closest?

Answer (score 9):

Following code will help to find the nearest neighbors of a selected point out of a set of points.

```
vector<Point2f> pointsForSearch; //Insert all 2D points to this vector
flann::KDTreeIndexParams indexParams;
flann::Index kdtree(Mat(pointsForSearch).reshape(1), indexParams);
vector<float> query;
query.push_back(pnt.x); //Insert the 2D point we need to find neighbours to the query
query.push_back(pnt.y); //Insert the 2D point we need to find neighbours to the query
vector<int> indices;
vector<float> dists;
kdtree.radiusSearch(query, indices, dists, range, numOfPoints);
```

indices gives the indexes of selected neighbors and dists gives the distances for selected neighbors.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/knearest-neighbors-opencv/) tutorial could be helpful.

It offers an example of training (as far as I know either using the `KNearest` constructor or `train()` method; check the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/k_nearest_neighbors.html#cvknearest)) and recognizing items (by utilizing, as @sietschie mentioned `find_nearest()` method).

[`find_nearest()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html#cvknearest-find-nearest) takes an `int k` value representing the needed amount of neighbors upon which classification is based, the k neighbors' labels could be optionally returned  through the parameter `neighborResponses`, as taken from `find_nearest()` documentation linked earlier:

> **neighborResponses** – Optional output values for corresponding
>   neighbors.

where, again as part of the documentation, `neighbors` are:

> **neighbors** – Optional output pointers to the neighbor vectors
>   themselves.

I'm not experienced with those parameters, however provided I understood correctly, **neighbors** offer the actual neighbors' values, while **neighborResponses** offers their labels.

Comment: The requested URL /2010/10/k-nearest-neighbors-in-opencv/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Thanks @JürgenK.; the blog seems to have been revamped - I updated the url.

Comment: i get a timeout on request of the documentation

Comment: True, I checked the website itself and it seems down.

Answer (score 2):

Here is small example how to find 3 closest points to (370,464):

```
#include "opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp"

vector<Point2f> cloud2d;
flann::KDTreeIndexParams indexParams;
flann::Index kdtree(Mat(cloud2d).reshape(1), indexParams);
vector<float> query;
query.push_back(370); 
query.push_back(464); 
vector<int> indices;
vector<float> dists;
kdtree.knnSearch(query, indices, dists, 3);
// cloud2d[indices[0]] -- is your first point now
// cloud2d[indices[1]] and cloud2d[indices[2]] -- is your 2nd and 3rd point
```

Please note that function behaves crazy if some of points have NAN coordinates, this may be the case if you divide by 0.0 somewhere before.

Comment: How do you setup cloud2d. I have a std::vector<cv::Point>

Comment: try vector<Point2f>

Answer (score 1):

You could use the k Nearest Neighbour classifier `CvKNearest`. After you trained the classifier with all your points you can get the `k` nearest neighbours with calling the function  `CvKNearest::find_nearest`.